# MVC Validate function of IValidatableObject not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My model looks like

```
public class MPariData : IValidatableObject
{
    public int moneyObtain { get; set; }
    public string IBAN { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var fields = new[] { "IBAN" };

        if (moneyObtain == 2)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Required field" ,fields);
        }
    }
}
```

I want if `moneyObtains == 2`,  `IBAN` field to be required.
My view looks like:

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IBAN, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IBAN)
</div>
```

But without success. My validation message doesn't appear and in my controller `ModelState` is always valid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it worked:
For the model:

```
    public int moneyObtain { get; set; }
    public string IBAN { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        List<ValidationResult> result = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (moneyObtain == 2)
        {
            result.Add(new ValidationResult("Required field", new string[] { "IBAN" }));  
            return result;
        }
```

...

For the view:
....

```
 <tr>
      <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.moneyObtain)</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.moneyObtain)</td>
      <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.moneyObtain)</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IBAN)</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IBAN)</td>
      <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IBAN)</td>
 </tr>
```

...